# DAX - What % of Months hit the Target

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am trying to create a measure to calculate what % of months that TOP2 surveys hit my target.

Here is my Dataset.

Dept_Surveys

[image]

I got 100% TOP2 surveys in Nov-2020,30% in Dec-2020 and 75% in Jan-2021

I have one more table which contains the actual targets for each department.

Dept_Targets

[image]

```
Var __TOP2%byMonth =
SUMMARIZE (
    Dept_Surveys,
    Dept_Surveys[Dept],
    Dept_Surveys[MM-YY],
    "@Perc",
        DIVIDE (
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( Dept_Surveys[SurveyID] ),
                FILTER ( Dept_Surveys, Dept_Surveys[category] = "TOP2" )
            ),
            CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Dept_Surveys[SurveyID] ) )
        ) * 100
)
```

I am getting the below results from this DAX.

[image]

```
Total_Months =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Dept_Surveys[MM-YY] )
)
```

So here, my marketing dept hit the target in Nov-2020 and Jan-2021 (which is greater than 70 from Dept_Targets) I need to calculate What % of months actually hit the target.

here i should get 2/3 = 65%

I need to do compare if TOP2 survey % hit the actual target and finally I need to measure what % of months hit the target

Comment: which part do you have a problem with?

Comment: @msta42a, I am trying to compare my "Perc" by MM-YY and Dept from Var __TOP2%byMonth with Targets I have for each dept (Dept_Targets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have model:

[image]

```
Perc = 
        DIVIDE (
            CALCULATE (
                countrows( VALUES( Dept_Surveys[SurveyID] )),
                FILTER ( Dept_Surveys, Dept_Surveys[Survey] = "TOP2" )
            ),
            CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Dept_Surveys[SurveyID] ) )
        ) * 100
```

Then:

```
Measure = 
var __Dept = SELECTEDVALUE(Dept_Surveys[Dept])
var __Perc = [Perc]
var __Target = calculate(max(Dept_Targets[Target]), Dept_Targets[Dept] = __Dept)
return
if(__Perc >= __Target, 1,0)
```

After That:

```
Measure 2 = 
var __Meettmp =  ADDCOLUMNS(ALL(Dept_Surveys[Dept],Dept_Surveys[MM-YY]), "XX", [Measure])
var __count = COUNTROWS(__Meettmp)
var __Meet = SUMX(__Meettmp, [XX])
return
DIVIDE(__Meet, __count)
```

[image]

Comment: ,Thanks for your help on this. just one question,I am using a 'Date' Table in my model  which I mapped with the Dept_Surveys table and I want to use MM-YY from my 'Date' table, can you help me how I can use Date[MM-YY] instead of Dept_Surveys[MM-YY] in this DAX, i tried to replace ADDCOLUMNS(ALL(Dept_Surveys[Dept], Date[MM-YY]), "XX", [Measure]) and it is not working.

Comment: Instead of ALL use SUMMARIZE(Dept_Surveys, Dept_Surveys[Dept], Date[MM-YY])